# Prisma seed - cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findFirst')

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, prisma, ts-node

I have a weird issue using prisma seed that I've never faced before and struggling to understand what causes it. The app is hosted in a nextjs full-stack project.

I have the following prisma init script:

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default prisma;
```

When using prisma in my app (`next dev`), everything works and the queries are being executed.

When I try to run the seed script however, it fails with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findFirst')`

Here is the seed script:

```
async function main() {
  const existingUser = await db.user.findFirst();

  // ...not relevant
}

main()
  .then(async () => await db.$disconnect())
  .catch(async e => {
    console.error(e);
    await db.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

package.json prisma section:

```json
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node src/server/db/seed.ts",
    "schema": "src/server/db/schema.prisma"
  },
```

tsconfig.json ts-node section:

```json
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"],
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
```

Printing the prisma client on the seed script returns `{}`, instead of the actual instance that I can see while printing in dev mode.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few debugging hours later, I finally found the issue. This code fragment is located in the prisma runtime config:

```js
  const dmmfModelKeys = Object.keys(client._baseDmmf.modelMap);
  const jsModelKeys = dmmfModelKeys.map(dmmfToJSModelName);
  const allKeys = [...new Set(dmmfModelKeys.concat(jsModelKeys))];
```

I have seen that while the first 2 variables were outputting a result, creating a `new Set` was actually returning an empty array, instead of the real value.

By default, NextJS uses `es5` as a target in tsconfig. ES5 however does not yet have the `Set` construct, which was causing the problem.

Upgrading to `es2015` solved the problem.

I was just expecting some kind of an error, instead of silent fail..

Comment: How to do uprade nextjs to ES205? Is it in next.config.js?

Comment: @bandungeuy, that's the compilation target in your tsconfig